# What is the difference between CreateGraphics and a Paint event's Graphics object?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

Can someone explain the difference between the `Graphics` object that is passed as `pevent.Graphics` and the one that is returned by a call to `this.CreateGraphics()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a `Paint` event is raised, you are given a `Graphics` object to draw into. This is passed as `pevent.Graphics`. Drawing into this `Graphics` object is how you paint the element.

`CreateGraphics` should basically never be used. It creates a new `Graphics` object on-the-fly from a window handle. You can draw into the `Graphics` object it returns, but anything you draw into it will be obliterated the next time that a `Paint` event is raised.

The only time you might want to use `CreateGraphics` is for special effects, like showing real-time feedback during a drag. You *want* that to be erased the next time that the element is repainted, so you go ahead and use `CreateGraphics` to get a temporary canvas to draw onto while the drag event is in progress.

You will *never* use `CreateGraphics` inside of a `Paint` event handler method. There is no point—you are given a `Graphics` object to draw into already!

Comment: Hear, hear.  The `Graphics` object provided by the `Paint` event would be created by a call to `CreateGraphics` in the first place but there's almost never a reason for you to call it yourself.  Unfortunately there are a lot of lazy examples around that use `CreateGraphics` for simplicity but fail to mention to the beginner reading it that they should never do so themselves.

Comment: Conceptually, yes, but not exactly true in practice. A `Paint` event is raised when the underlying Windows operating system sends the window a `WM_PAINT` message, and along with this message comes a handle to a device canvas (DC) to draw into. Since WinForms uses GDI+ instead of GDI, it converts this DC into a Graphics object and passes that along to the `Paint` event handler.

Comment: As far as I know, one situation where you need to call `CreateGraphics` is calls to measurement functions when you're doing something like hit detection. For example, if you're clicking a checkbox, you need to call `GetGlyphSize` which requires a `Graphics`, and if you're doing it in a mouse event, you don't already have one.