# How to make my game engine faster (GDI+, C#)

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

I'm currently building a 2D Game Engine in C#, using GDI. I do know that there are better alternatives to GDI but I'm also so deep into the project I can't turn back now.

So, I currently have a graphics engine, that renders a portion of a bitmap, depending on what my cameras position and windows size is, which has given me a great performance boost. Great!

However, I've noticed that if I place a bunch of game objects, in the same position, I get the same frame rate compared to if I placed the objects in different positions.

So, maybe the graphics engine is rendering parts of the bitmap that don't need to be rendered? and if this is the case how do I fix it?

I believe code isn't really needed, but just to be sure here's what my graphics engine is doing during my main game loop

```
namespace GameEngine.Graphics
{
    public class GraphicsEngine
    {
        private Window window;
        private View view;

        private System.Drawing.Graphics frontBuffer;
        private System.Drawing.Graphics backBuffer;
        private System.Drawing.Bitmap backBufferBitmap;

        public GraphicsEngine(Window window, View view)
        {
            this.window = window;
            this.view = view;

            frontBuffer = window.CreateGraphics();
            backBufferBitmap = new Bitmap((int)view.Size.X, (int)view.Size.Y);
            backBuffer = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(backBufferBitmap);

            frontBuffer.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            frontBuffer.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear;
            frontBuffer.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            frontBuffer.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;  
            frontBuffer.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
            frontBuffer.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;

            backBuffer.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            backBuffer.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            backBuffer.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            backBuffer.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
            backBuffer.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
            backBuffer.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            frontBuffer.DrawImage(backBufferBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, window.Width, window.Height),
                                                    new Rectangle((int)view.Position.X, (int)view.Position.Y,
                                                    (int)view.Dimensions.X, (int)view.Dimensions.Y), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: You'd need to decide if bits of your items placed on top of each other would be visible, and if not, dont draw them

Comment: @Joey, Yes sorry I'll fix that up now.

Comment: @BugFinder, so there's no parameter I can change in the graphics object or bitmap?

Comment: Im not a GDI/GDI+ expert, but I dont believe there is.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I heard that `x.CreateGraphics()` is a huge performance decreaser. Maybe with help from this link it will give it a boost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301743/what-is-the-difference-between-creategraphics-and-a-paint-events-graphics-objec

Comment: Culling game objects is very unlikely to pay off, you still need to have acceptable perf in worst-case conditions.  System.Drawing makes it *far* to easy to not pay attention to the pixel format of your bitmaps.  That is a convenience but picking the right one makes a big, big difference at runtime.  You want the one that is compatible with the pixel format of the video adapter's frame buffer so the bitmap pixels don't have to be converted.  Only one qualifies today, it is 32bppPArgb.  About x10 faster than all the other ones.