# Draw graphics on click and make them stay

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics

This little program opens a windows form and draws 70 red rectangles, where the user clicks on the form.

Every time the user clicks, the rectangles disappear, and new ones are drawn on the new click-Point.

I want to make the rectangles to stay when the user clicks and draws a new set of rectangles.

How do i do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace tegnRektangel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        bool mouseClicked = false;
        Graphics g = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseClicked)
            {
                g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
                paintRectangel();
            }


        }
        private void paintRectangel()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 70; i++)
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x - 50-i*5, y - 40-i*5, 100, 80);  
            }
            g.Dispose();

        }//end paint

        private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseClicked = true;
            Point clickPoint = new Point(e.X,e.Y);
            x = clickPoint.X;
            y = clickPoint.Y;
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to keep a collection of rectangles (or coordinates) for your `panel1` to draw. Currently it just paints your 'generated' rectangles and everything from the previous paint gets wiped when painting happens again.

Comment: Golden rule: never use CreateGraphics().

Comment: @HansPassant Can you suggest an alternative? I am actually curious because I have little experience with painting.

Comment: And don't store that graphic object.  Kill this: `Graphics g = null;`

Comment: @BlakeThingstad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301743/what-is-the-difference-between-creategraphics-and-a-paint-events-graphics-objec

Comment: @RyanSchaefer Thanks, so the PaintEventArgs already has a Graphics object given to you, no need to create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Graphics object that you retrieve through the CreateGraphics
>   method should not normally be retained after the current Windows
>   message has been processed, because anything painted with that object
>   will be erased with the next WM_PAINT message.

You can work around it like this:

- In the click event, add the (x, y) coordinate to a list of coordinates.
- In the paint event, iterate all these (x, y) coordinates and paint each rectangle.

Comment: I did this, and it absolutely worked. Makes sense too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to demonstrate creating rectangles for each click, storing them, and painting all stored rectangles.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Rectangle> Rectangles { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Rectangles.Count > 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Red, Rectangles.ToArray());
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 70; i++)
        {
            Rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(e.X - 50 - i * 5, e.Y - 40 - i * 5, 100, 80));
        }
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```